# Redis pub/sub Implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, redis

I am retrieving JSON data from 3 source urls

For example

```
data1 = HTTParty.get('url1')

data2 = HTTParty.get('url2')

data3 = HTTParty.get('url3')
```

I am hitting all the 3 urls once a 2 minute and the datas obtained in variables data1, data2 and data3 may vary or may not vary for every 2 minutes. Whenever the data changes it should be reflected in the variables data1, data2 and data3. I need to display the data from redis.

How to implement this with redis pub/sub method? [PubSub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just a draft:

1. When getting the data, hash it with SHA1() or equivalent hash function where you don't expect collisions.
2. Set the hashes into the corresponding Redis keys, however read the old value before setting a new one.
3. If the old value was different, use Redis `PUBLISH` in order to send a message to listeners.

With this schema however, if the listeners are disconnected, they'll lose the update forever. There are a few alternative:

1. Listeners could check the value of the key from time to time to check if it changed compared to their view.
2. Or... when a listener receives a message, it also sets a corresponding key with the hash of the last update received. This way from time to time your process that checks the json data, may also check that at least somebody received the latest update available, if not, you may re-publish.

Needs more work but I hope it's a start.